# how do I convert a tuple of floats to a tuple of integers

Tags: python, tuples

how do I convert a tuple of floats to ints?

```
tup = (1.0, 2.0,3.0) 
tupint = int(tup)
```

Comment: `tuple(map(int, tup))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need to convert to integer without rounding off:

```
>>> tuple(map(int, tup))
(1, 2, 3)
```

If you need rounded integer:

```
>>> tuple(map(round, tup))
(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: this looks nice but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Can you tell me why it doesn't work for you?

Comment: Works fine for me, and I tried it in both Python 2 and 3. Except in Python 2 the `round` version gives rounded floats.

Answer (score 3):

Use [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions), which is similar to [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
tup = (1.0, 2.0, 3.0) 
tupint = tuple(int(x) for x in tup)
print(tupint)
# (1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: That is not a list comprehension, that's call generator expression or generator comprehension.

Comment: @ThePyGuy Thanks, corrected name for the method to "generator expression".

Answer (score -1):

As already said in other comments, you can use this code below to convert a tuple of floats to a tuple of integers.

[image]

properly working for me. You may also use map to convert the tuple.